# How to find what went wrong with Keycloak login in iOS app using AeroGear

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, openid, keycloak, aerogear

I am trying to connect my iOS app to a Keycloak server for authentication purposes and have decided to use [AeroGear library](https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-ios-oauth2) to do it. I did the initial setup as described in the Readme and configured everything Server side. 
The code I am using to initiate login is this:

```
    let keycloakConfig = KeycloakConfig(
        clientId: "testclient",
        host: "http://localhost:8080",
        realm: "testrealm",
        isOpenIDConnect: true
    )
    let oauth2Module = AccountManager.addKeycloakAccount(config: keycloakConfig)
    //let oauth2Module = KeycloakOAuth2Module(config: keycloakConfig, session: UntrustedMemoryOAuth2Session(accountId: "ACCOUNT_FOR_CLIENTID_\(keycloakConfig.clientId)"))
    let http = Http()
    http.authzModule = oauth2Module
    oauth2Module.login {(accessToken: AnyObject?, claims: OpenIdClaim?, error: NSError?) in
        print("login successful")
        // some other stuff happens here
    }
```

The app takes me to login screen of Keycloak where I put in the user info and it seems like the login works as I get redirected back to my app. But for some reason nothing that should happen doesn't happen afterwards - for example the print to console. 
When I tried it in a different app it worked so it must be ok but I don't know how to debug this. The session on Keycloak seems alright so I have no idea what could cause this... 
I would appreciate some advice as I am very good at this.

Comment: Have you tried to run/take a look at or cookbook example app? 
https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-ios-cookbook/tree/master/SharedShoot
https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-backend-cookbook/tree/master/Shoot

Comment: @Passos this is what I started with and in the Shoot app it works, then I put the same code in my app and nothing happens.. I configured everything like it's described (added the right URI schemes to Keycloak) and everything happens like it should except for the code inside the login closure...

Comment: UPDATE: is it possible it's a closure problem? It seems to work as an @IBAction function? If so what would be the right workaround as I don't want to use it as an action..

Comment: That is really weird, you should not be able to use it only as an @IBAction

Comment: @Passos I know, right? And yet this is happening.. But anyway I did this via IBAction and got it to work so I guess it's a solution for now.

Comment: Hello @dj-neza , i need your help for keyclock , can you please help me in this